# How to stop carrying #hash on PHP redirect?

Tags: php

Basically every time I use header() to redirect I still carry any hash I had before. And it's producing bad results in the app, duplicate actions and such.

Trying to erase the hash with JS is no good since I cannot remove the #.

How can I remove it when redirecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be you who is using `#` in your `header()` because PHP does not put `#` while redirecting...

Correct syntax :

`header('Location: page.php');`

If your string is dynamically generated you can use a regex and you can remove `#` using `preg_replace()` before it assigns the url to `header()`

[header() Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: Its not necessarily the op who is adding the hash; I have the same problem. For example `header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');` `header('Location: /');` `exit;` Will keep the hash

Comment: @Hank he is not specifying any particular situation, he says `every time I use header() to redirect`

Comment: TO quote the entire sentence `Basically every time I use header() to redirect I still carry any hash I had before`. He is trying to remove a hash that is sent using a server side solution.

Comment: @Hank lets not decide before he clears out what he is actually doing as no code is provided here I gave a basic situation solution

Comment: I think Hank got the problem right. I specify the hash myself obviously not using PHP. But later when I do redirect with PHP I carry the hash over to the new address.